# Is it idiomatic to use "leapfrog" in reference to pain?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I have read the following sentence in [a site where English is the language required to post](https://drupal.org/project/zen).

> Sass/Compass             Complete Sass/Compass integration using best practices for Drupal/Sass. The Zen team has developed over the span of a year with blood, sweat and tears, but you can **leap frog the pain** by using what we've learned.
>
> CSS                              If you're not ready for Sass yet, Zen still includes a full set of well-documented CSS files. Sass integration adds *zero* overhead, so if you simply ignore all of Zen's Sass, your site performance isn't penalized. No worries!

(I didn't respect the original format, since the linked page uses a HTML table.)

Looking at the NOAD, I get the following definitions for *leapfrog*:

- Surpass or overtake another to move into a leading or dominant position
- Pass over (a stage or obstacle)

In the first case, the verb is not used with an object, but it is used as in the following sentence:

> She leapfrogged into a sales position.

In the second case, the verb requires an object, and it is used as in the following sentence:

> She attempted to leapfrog the barriers of class.

Is idiomatic to say "leapfrog the pain"? Can *leapfrog* be used in a more extended way than the way shown by the dictionary?

Comment: If used as a verb, you should it write it as one word, *leapfrog*.

Comment: I quoted what I read on Internet. The dictionary shows the verb is _leapfrog_, not _leap frog_, and I would write _leapfrog_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the second meaning in use here, that is:

> Pass over (a stage or obstacle)

In this case, the "stage or obstacle" is the "pain" involved in the learning curve. The sentence is essentially saying:

> It was a lot of work the past year, but, if you learn from what we've learned, it might not necessarily take you a full year to accomplish the same thing.

where the authors have elected to shorten "hassle of learning" with the single word "pain."

The phrase "leapfrog the pain" isn't necessarily idiomatic, but, in this case, *pain* isn't much different from *barriers* (at least not syntactically).

That said, the phrase "[blood, sweat and tears](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blood-sweat-and-tears_1)" is very idiomatic, and it means "a tremendous amount of hard work and effort." It's important in this sentence, because it helps the reader understand what *pain* is referring to.

Comment: I would have expected to read "you can leapfrog the creation of a good theme"; I get _the pain_ means _the pain of creating a good theme_, but saying _the pain_ sounds like saying _a glass of wine_, where you replace the container for the content. (In this case, [Zen](https://drupal.org/project/zen) is merely the name of Drupal theme, not anything related to philosphy. `:)`)

Comment: @kia: No, I think I'd say, "you can leapfrog **to** the creation of a good theme." To get to someplace good in a hurry, you leapfrog _to_ (or _into_) it. When avoiding something painful, you just leapfrog it (or maybe leapfrog _over_ it, but I think _over_ is implied in many usages). Ribbit :^)

Comment: I was imagining that creating a good theme is something painful, I avoid it, so I leapfrog it. ("I leapfrog the creation of a good theme.") I see that _leapfrog the pain_ is not much different from _leapfrog the barriers of class_, since in both the cases there isn't anything physical to pass over. "Cra cra," replied the Italian frog.

Comment: @kia: In the context of this sentence, creating a good theme is only painful if you don't use the lessons learned from the author's experience. In the author's context, you don't want to "leapfrog" the creation of a good theme, but you DO want to "leapfrog" the creation of a good theme **the hard way**.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not idiomatic. "Leapfrog" implies that you are in competition with someone (or something) else toward some goal. With pain, you are not in competition with the pain for a third thing; your are fighting against the pain.

It also has a meaning of "pass over", but this only applies in certain circumstances where a goal in sight.

I would say "but you can avoid the pain"—or rephrase the sentence as "but you don't have to go through this pain yourself if you use what we've learned".

**Update:** Another word that could be used to replace "leapfrog" in this sentence is "bypass".